# Search for a JList

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jlist, keylistener

I am looking for a way to create a searchbox linked to a jlist, so that when the user types a sequence of characters, it will search and match to a JList item, then highlight that item.
I have created a jtextfield and added a keylistener.
This part of the code works properly, but only for the first character the user types. I am trying to expand this to any number of characters the user types. Any ideas how to achieve that? Thank you in advance

```
String[] feedStrings = {"aaa", "abc", "opo","oiuu"}

JList feedList = new JList(feedStrings);

feedList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
feedList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);

feedList.setVisibleRowCount(4);


                JTextField searchbox = new JTextField();
        searchbox.setColumns(8);
        searchbox.setVisible(true);


        searchbox.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                  String text = "" + e.getKeyChar();
                  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                  buffer.append(text);
                  String strbuf = buffer.toString();

                  int index = feedList.getNextMatch(strbuf, 0, Position.Bias.Forward);
                  System.out.println(index);
                  feedList.setSelectedIndex(index);
            }
      });
```

Comment: You should never be using a KeyListener on a text component, and in fact should hardly ever use KeyListeners period. Perhaps you want to use a DocumentListener instead on the JTextField's Document.

Comment: Consider using a single column `JTable` instead.  It is possible to add a [`RowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html) to a table, and it can also be used as a row filter.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Google **auto complete with java** I'm sure you'll find something. I have in the past. Too lazy to do it for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what would be a good alternative for that if you modify the document in the event?

Answer (score 1):

> but only for the first character the user types. I am trying to expand this to any number of characters the user types

Just use the text from the Document. That is another reason to be using a DocumentListener and NOT a KeyListener.

Although I like the suggestion to use a JTable. The Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` even has a working example that shows you exactly how to do this. You can find the link to the tutorial by reading the JTable API.